# Field 'vaccine_id' doesn't have a default value

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-9

why i'm getting this error?

> First view

```
`    @foreach ($appointments as $appointment)
        <div class="card m-2 p-2">
            <div class="card-body">
                <h6 class="card-title">Vaccine: {{ $appointment->vaccine }}</h6>
                
                <div class="mb-6" style="float: right; margin-top: 10px">
                    <form action="/appointment/{{ $appointment->id }}">
                        <input type="submit" class="bg-black text-white rounded py-2 px-4 hover:bg-black"
                            value="Schedule Now">
                    </form>
                </div>

            </div>
        </div>
    @endforeach`
```

> First view Controller

```
`    public function showAppointment()
    {
        return view('appointmentForm');
    }`
```

> Second View

```
`    <form action="/appointment/create" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="POST">
        @csrf
        <div class="name">
            <label for="name" class="form-label">Name:</label>
            <input type="text" name="name" id="name" placeholder="Enter name">
        </div>
    </form>`
```

> Route

```
    `Route::get('/appointment/{id}', [AppointmentController::class, 'showAppointment'])->middleware('guest');`
```

```
`    public function showAppointment()
    {
        return view('appointmentForm');
    }`
```

> i have two migration file

```
`    Schema::create('appointments', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->id();
        $table->string('vaccine');
        $table->timestamps();
    });`
```

```
`    Schema::create('usersappointments', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->id();
        $table->foreignId('vaccine_id')->constrained('appointments')->onUpdate('cascade')->onDelete('cascade');
        $table->string('name');
        $table->timestamps();
    });`
```

> Model

```
 `   protected $fillable = [
        'vaccine_id', 'name'
    ];`
```

> Controller

```
`    public function createAppointment(Request $request)
    {        
        $data = $request->validate([
            'name' => 'required'
        ]);
        
        usersappointments::create($data);

        return redirect('/');
    }`
```

This is how it works; the user select vaccines he want then he will redirect to a page which he will input his name but i'm getting this error

Comment: `vaccine_id` field is not getting data

Comment: you need to set `vaccine_id` input in your second view form

Comment: `vaccine_id` is required in the database (not nullable) and not present when you save to the database. add it to your form, and validate your request. Or make the field nullable if that is the case

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0):

You need to set input `vaccine_id` in second view in order to send data to controller

```
    <form action="/appointment/create" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="POST">
    @csrf
    <div class="name">
        <label for="name" class="form-label">Name:</label>

        <input type="hidden" name="vaccine_id" value="" /> // here get the vaccine_id in value which is selected in first view 

        <input type="text" name="name" id="name" placeholder="Enter name">
    </div>
 </form>
```